# Tweepy: get all friends of a sample of twitter accounts: how to handle protected users

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to look up all the friends (meaning the twitter users one is following) of a sample of friends of one twitter account, to see what other friends they have in common. The problem is that I don't know how to handle protected accounts, and I keep running into this error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Not authorized.
```

This is the code I have:

```
...
screen_name = ----
file_name = "followers_data/follower_ids-" + screen_name + ".txt"
with open(file_name) as file:
ids = file.readlines()

num_samples = 30
ids = [x.strip() for x in ids]
friends = [[] for i in range(num_samples)]

for i in range(0, num_samples):
    id = random.choice(ids)
    for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, id).items():
        print(friend)
        friends[i].append(friend)
```

I have a list of all friends from one account `screen_name`, from which I load the friend ids. I then want to sample a few of those and look up their friends.

I have also tried something like this:

```
def limit_handled(cursor, name):
    try:
        yield cursor.next()
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print("Something went wrong... ", name)
        pass

for i in range(0, num_samples):
    id = random.choice(ids)
    items = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, id).items()
    for friend in limit_handled(items, id):
        print(friend)
        friends[i].append(friend)
```

But then it seems like only one friend per sample friend is stored before moving on to the next sample. I'm pretty new to Python and Tweepy so if anything looks weird, please let me know.

Comment: your indentation appears to be a bit off. Please correct this.

Comment: there's a few things to change about this, I'll take a look at it when I'm free in a little while if no-one has answered it by then. One question - do you want the accounts you can't view to be included as one of your sample, or do you want to replace it with an account you can view (if possible)?

Comment: No I don't need the accounts I can't view, it is enough to replace them with another account. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a couple of comments on naming. The names `file` and `id` are protected, so you should avoid using them to name variables - I have changes these.

Secondly, when you initialise your tweepy API, it's clever enough to deal with rate limits if you use `wait_on_rate_limit=True` and will inform you when it's delayed due to rate limits if you use `wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True`.

You also lose some information when you set `friends = [[] for i in range(num_samples)]`, as you then won't be able to associate the friends you find with the account they relate to. You can instead use a dictionary, which will associate each ID used with the friends found, allowing for better processing.

My corrected code is as follows:

```
import tweepy
import random

consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...'
access_token = '...'
access_token_secret = '...'

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication. Use rate limits.
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

screen_name = '----'
file_name = "followers_data/follower_ids-" + screen_name + ".txt"
with open(file_name) as f:
    ids = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

num_samples = 30
friends = dict()

# Initialise i
i = 0

# We want to check that i is less than our number of samples, but we also need to make
# sure there are IDs left to choose from.
while i <= num_samples and ids:
    current_id = random.choice(ids)

    # remove the ID we're testing from the list, so we don't pick it again.
    ids.remove(current_id)

    try:
        # try to get friends, and add them to our dictionary value if we can
        # use .get() to cope with the first loop.
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, current_id).pages():
            friends[current_id] = friends.get(current_id, []) + page
        i += 1
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        # we get a tweep error when we can't view a user - skip them and move onto the next.
        # don't increment i as we want to replace this user with someone else.
        print 'Could not view user {}, skipping...'.format(current_id)
```

The output is a dictionary, `friends`, with keys of user IDs and items of the friends for each user.